# Cannot resolve symbol Theme.AppCompat after updating com.android.tools.build:gradle to 2.3.0-beta1

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I had this problem after updating `com.android.tools.build:gradle` from project to 2.3.0-beta1. 
If I set back to 2.2.3, the `Theme.AppCompat` style recognizes.

I don't want to set it to 2.2.3 because the project can't be out of time.

Here is the error's print:

[image]

My project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

My app's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 76
        versionName "1.18.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }

    repositories {

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }

}

repositories {

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile(name: 'libctfclient-sdk', ext: 'aar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library-extra:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:0.9.9'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
}
```

In order of that error, I have this problem:

[image]

I already tried:

- `Invalidate Caches\Restart`;
- Update android support library to the last version;
- Clean and Rebuild the project;

Does anyone know how to solve this problem without setting project's `build.gradle` to 2.2.3?

Answer (score 3):

As said in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42765120/3825764,

"build cache" is enabled by default in build Android Plugin since 2.3.0. It creates files in build cache outside of project folder (e.g. in \Users\%username%.android\build-cache). Theese files are intended to be common between your projects.

And then Android Studio is unable to navigate in theese files.

You can disable Build Cache in gradle.properties file. just add android.enableBuildCache=false

Answer (score 1):

I used android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta3 and had the same problem. I've upgraded Android Studio 2.2.3 to 2.3 beta 2 and everything had worked.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart did not resolve the issue.

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle showed Use local gradle distribution selected with Gradle home: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1 and a warning displayed saying the gradle location was incorrect.

Resolved issue by selecting Use default gradle wrapper (recommended).
Probably just pointing to the new local distribution location would also work.

Answer (score -1):

Try: File -> "Invalidate Cashes\Restart"

Can be just problem of android studio

Comment: I did it already, but no success. I will add it to question, I forgot

Comment: Did you tried to delete .gradle from project directory? Two days my project was like: cannot resolve getResources() method. After removing .gradle, everything worked.

Comment: I didn't yet. I'll try it. Thanks!!