# Styles.xml not working in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have created an app in android studio in ubuntu. Now I have moved the project to Windows 10. I have updated the studio now.
The styles.xml resources are unable to identify the themes given in the parent attribute(all of them).

This is my styles.xml file

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style  name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#f44336</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#e53935</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#f44336</item>
    <item name="showcaseViewStyle">@style/CustomShowcaseTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</style>

<style name="checkbox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
</style>



<style name="layoutmargin">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">20dp</item>
</style>


<style name="CustomShowcaseTheme" parent="ShowcaseView.Light">
    <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#90234A56</item>
    <item name="sv_buttonBackgroundColor">#CF3119</item>
    <item name="sv_buttonText">Close</item>
    <item name="sv_titleTextAppearance">@style/CustomTitle</item>
    <item name="sv_detailTextAppearance">@style/CustomDetailText</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTitle" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDetailText" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

All the parent attributes are showing that symbol cannot be resolved.

Comment: that's because of feature called "build cache". see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42765120/1148784

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the Android SDK version is the same as on your Ubuntu system? I am not sure if it is an issue with Android studio itself or the SDK. Did you also try to rebuild the project? Internal IDE parsing errors are not always reliable

Comment: Sdk version is diiferent. Now what should I do to get it working?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.You want me to install old sdk version or something else?

Comment: You need the corresponding API version of Android to use your styles. If you compare it with your SDK on Ubuntu there must be a certain API level (ex v24) and also others I guess, and you also need them on Windows, installable via SDK Manager