# Cannot Resolve Symbol Theme, Themeoverlay, and widget Appcompat

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

Earlier before everything was fine but now when I reopen my Android project, inside the values folder in styles, most of the parent is being highlighted in red. I don't understand why and how to resolve it. when I compile the project it works fine but I just want to remove the errors. Below is the error file

Here is the image file:

[image: Here is the image file]

and my app build file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nepalpolice.cdp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 15
        versionName "15.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/project.properties'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'allclasses-frame.html'
        }

    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}





dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    implementation files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

And my build gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nepalpolice.cdp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 15
        versionName "15.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/project.properties'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'allclasses-frame.html'
        }

    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}





dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    implementation files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

I tried to clean and run project, but still issue hasn't been fixed.

Comment: yes on about section it say 3.1

Comment: @MikeM. that seems to remove the problem but only when I replaced compiledSDKversion to 27 instead of 26 . But still I have targetSDK version to 26.should I also change this to 27?? willl it cause any problem?

Comment: Generally, the reason why it happened is ```'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
``` How about specifying version? (Most people doesn't recommend using '+') ```'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
``` and also, ```'com.android.support:design-v4:26.1.0'```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726293/cannot-resolve-symbol-theme-themeoverlay/50432590#50432590) post has the same roots too.
Anyway just two steps helped me:

1.Close the project from the File menu.
2.Open the project again as existing Android Studio project.