# Android Studio - Cannot resolve symbol themes, colorprimary,

Tags: android-appcompat, android-studio-3.0

I am seeing in **Android Studio 3.1.2** an error for **AppCompat themes and colors attributes** like **attr/colorPrimary**.

But only in Android Studio. Compile and run does work.

**For example:**

[image]

[image]

**My app.gradle:**
[image]

supportLibVersion is 27.1.1!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This helped in the [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726293/cannot-resolve-symbol-theme-themeoverlay/50432590#50432590). Maybe this help you:

Close the project from the File menu. Then open the project again as existing Android Studio project.

Answer (score 2):

I posted my answer on link mentioned by V.March. Basicly Invalidate Caches / Restart solved my problem