# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed on android 3.2.1 SDK 28.0.3

Tags: android, android-appcompat

REVISED: got a new error after upgrading to AS(3.2.1) and Gradle(4.6).

Here is build.gradle code. Gradle property has "
android.enableAapt2 = true" and wrapper property has "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/CHANGES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'mediarouter-v7'
        all*.exclude module: 'support-compat'
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    implementation 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The new error is

```
    Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_tint_default.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_tint_edittext.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_tint_spinner.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:21: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-28.0.0.aar\d2abd1d1eab13b237ffd0fc5d63d6820\res\color\design_tint_password_toggle.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.abc.app:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:23: error: resource layout/notification_template_icon_group (aka com.abc.app:layout/notification_template_icon_group) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:23: error: resource dimen/notification_large_icon_height (aka com.abc.app:dimen/notification_large_icon_height) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:23: error: resource dimen/notification_large_icon_width (aka com.abc.app:dimen/notification_large_icon_width) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: error: resource dimen/notification_large_icon_width (aka com.abc.app:dimen/notification_large_icon_width) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: error: resource dimen/notification_large_icon_width (aka com.abc.app:dimen/notification_large_icon_width) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:23: error: resource layout/notification_template_icon_group (aka com.abc.app:layout/notification_template_icon_group) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:23: error: resource dimen/notification_large_icon_height (aka com.abc.app:dimen/notification_large_icon_height) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:23: error: resource dimen/notification_large_icon_width (aka com.abc.app:dimen/notification_large_icon_width) not found.
C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-28.0.0.aar\f0a6c1a9d43f0b2d6cca2c26c28e9e86\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:34: error: resource dimen/notification_large_icon_height (aka com.abc.app:dimen/notification_large_icon_height) not found.
```

Tried many solutions including Invalidate Caches/Restart,  Close and Import Project, remove cache file, reinstall Android Studio, Clean & Rebuild. None of them could make the project build successfully.

Any other possible solutions?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet, still trying...

Comment: Figured it out for me, at least, posted suggestion below!

Comment: have you tried `File->Invalidate Caches / Restart...`?

Comment: After that comment out dependencies in build.gradle then sync, then clean the project then bring back the dependencies then sync again.

Comment: Tried Invalidate Caches / Restart, not working

Comment: Comment out is not working as well.

Comment: @Eric Are there any errors/warnings in '\res\color\*.xml' or '\res\layout\*.xml' files?

Comment: @Eric have you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your `gradle` caches. For example, on Windows:

```
C:\Users\[username]\.gradle\caches
```

then perform the following:

1. `Android Studio>File>Sync with File System`
2. `Android Studio>File>Sync Project with Gradle Files`
3. `Android Studio>Build> Clean Project`
4. `Android Studio>Build> Rebuild Project`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried and got this error "Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed"

Comment: The error detail is "Output:  C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\888450102b7519d6fb3ec4fed42688ef\res\color\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka com.company.app:alpha) not found."

Comment: After deleting caches, got a new issue. The question is revised. Any good idea? Thanks!

Comment: Silly question, but you force a sync?

Answer (score 0):

In such situations where you can't find the source of bug, try to create a new project and then first, only copy your `.java` files into the new project then, try to copy your `layout` and `drawable` folders.
Then try to add your `dependencies` in the `build.gradle` file  one by one syncing after each add to see which one is causing the problem.

Also I should mention some recommendations in your `build.gradle`:

First move this line to the top:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Right after `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Also I advise you to migrate to Androidx instead of Support libraries.

Also I wouldn't use jakewharton's butterknife anymore. There is View Binding in Android now. use that: explained [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)